# What is with that orange box?

Tags: discussion, review, user-interface

I feel like that I should know this by now and that I might have known at some point, but at any rate: what does this number in the orange box indicate?

[image: Image of top-bar showing an orange box with a number in it]

<strike>There is also a blue box that appears to its left that I find equally baffling. An explanation would be appreciated.</strike> (Comment: the blue box got removed, mods still have one.)

---

Well, now that the meat of the mystery has been solved, here's my next question: why are there so many fewer posts actually "awaiting review" than the box would suggest?

Comment: What have you tried? (e.g., clicking it?)

Comment: ...or hovering?

Comment: Hovering did it!  Thank you, that's a bit embarrassing.

Comment: @Thursday to be fair, though, clicking it tells you that it has something to do with review.  However, there does not to be a correspondence between the number in the box and the number of "posts awaiting review", as the hover-text so boldly claims.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For 10k+ users those are posts awaiting review, but not necessarily *your* review. SE developers found it [too expensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231052/) to compute the number for every user individually (given that users load question pages a lot more often than they load `/review`).

The orange box serves some purpose: it appears only when the number of pending reviews is 10 or more, indicating that some backlog may be building up. But the number itself is not that useful.

For 2k+ (yet not 10k+) those are the pending suggested edits.

<strike>Blue box is the number of suggested edits pending review. (If I remember correctly; I got rid of these lights, along with green reputation changes, long time ago.)</strike>